# what is the java float default precision

Tags: java

The code is :

```
public static void main(String [] args) {

    float f = 5.69f;

    String floatStr = String.format("%.15f", f);
    System.out.println(f);
    System.out.println(floatStr);
}
```

The f is 5.69.
The floatStr is 5.690000057220459.
Is there a default precision for System.out.println ?

Comment: Your title and question don't ask the same thing. *"what is the java float default precision"* and *" Is there a default precision for System.out.println?"* are different questions.

Answer (score 2):

`float`, itself, has no specific precision. It's a *floating point* number, specifically an IEEE-754 32-bit binary floating point number.

Re your `println` question, it's not `println`, it's how the float is converted to `String`. This is covered by the JavaDoc for [`Float.toString(float)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Float.html#toString-float-):

> How many digits must be printed for the fractional part of *m* or *a*? There must be at least one digit to represent the fractional part, and beyond that as many, but only as many, more digits as are needed to uniquely distinguish the argument value from adjacent values of type float. That is, suppose that *x* is the exact mathematical value represented by the decimal representation produced by this method for a finite nonzero argument *f*. Then *f* must be the `float` value nearest to *x*; or, if two float values are equally close to *x*, then *f* must be one of them and the least significant bit of the significand of *f* must be 0.

Or to put it another way, the default `String` only has as many digits as necessary that if you took that `String` and converted back to `float`, you'd get the same `float` value.